# How to compare two lists of lists of strings

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare 2 collection with lists of strings.
1st object with list of strings:

> a0, b0, c0
>
> a1, b1, c0
>
> a1, b2, c0
>
> a1, b2, c1

2nd

> a0, b0, c0
>
> a1, b2, c0

I have method go get list of string from object

```
public List<string> GetPlainRow(int index)
{
    if(index >= _countRows || index < 0)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    List<string> returnedRow = new List<string>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in _dataRows)
    {
        returnedRow.Add(entry.Value[index]);
    }
    return returnedRow;
}
```

Tried to compare objects lists with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataCollection.CountRows; i++)
{
    var newRow = table.NewRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < dataCollection.GetPlainRow(i).Count; j++)
    {
        newRow[j] = dataCollection.GetPlainRow(i)[j];

    }
    for (int k = 0; k < dataCollection.CountRows; k++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < dataRestrained.CountRows; l++)
        {
           if(dataCollection.GetPlainRow(k).SequenceEqual(dataRestrained.GetPlainRow(l)))
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    newRow[dataCollection.CountRows - 2] = found;
    found = false;
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

But it seems like everytime its returning true, but when i've used Equals instead of SequenceEqual it was returning false.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: `Equals` for two lists will only return true if the two list variables reference the same instance, not if they contain the same data.  `SequenceEqual` will actually check the data inside of the lists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two List<String> to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602579/how-to-compare-two-liststring-to-each-other)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the desired output. If the input is two `List<List<string>>` variables described above, what is the output?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare" in this context?

Comment: Im trying to create DataTable for DataGrid, DataTable. DataTable is basically 1st list of lists of strings, but there is additional column with true/false. Wanted to make true if certain 2nd list element is on 1st list, and false if not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make thing simple i add a class for the result:

```
   internal class Result
            {
                public List<string> List { get; set; }
                public bool IsExisted { get; set; }
            }
```

then i have made an EqualityComparer ....

```
  internal class ListOfStringEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
        {
            public bool Equals(List<string> b1, List<string> b2)
            {
                if (b1.Count != b2.Count) return false;
                for (int i = 0; i < b1.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (b1[i] != b2[i]) return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(List<string> b2)
            {
                int hCode = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < b2.Count; i++)
                {
                    hCode = EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(b2[i]);
                }
                return hCode.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

now you can try this:

```
 ListOfStringEqualityComparer  listOfStringEqualityComparer= new ListOfStringEqualityComparer();
        var q = (from c in bigList
                 select new Result() { List = new List<string>(c), IsExisted = smallList.Contains(c, listOfStringEqualityComparer) });
```

let me now if it help ...

Comment: Just forget about list of lists of strings. Lets take it as list of strings. I have couple of lists of strings, lets say they are 'A', and i have couple of lists of strings - 'B'. 'A' has every list which is in 'B'. DataGrid is based on 'A' with extra column with true/false. I wanted to compare A with B. If 'A' element being compared at the moment is in 'B' column for this list will be true, if its not in 'B' it will be false

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
class Someclass
{
  string data;
  bool found;
}

Someclass data = A.Select(c => new Someclass(){data = c, found = B.Contains(c)});
```