# How to compare two List<string[]> in C#

Tags: c#, compare

**Automation** - selenium using C#

We are reading a table which returns value in `List<string[]>`. We need to compare the values before and after an action performed, which should not affect the table content.

Is there a way to compare both

```
List<string[]> ExpRequestItemsWithSection
```

with

```
List<string[]> ActRequestItemsWithSection
```

Till now i was using below code and it works fine. But is there any *other way* to compare both the collections? Any idea of making this quicker and less resource intensive as i need to process a lot of lists?

```
bool isRequestsMatch = true;

for (int i = 0; i < ActRequestItemsWithSection.Count; i++)
{
  if (!((ActRequestItemsWithSection[i][0] == ExpRequestItemsWithSection[i][0]) && 
     (ActRequestItemsWithSection[i][1] == ExpRequestItemsWithSection[i][1])))
    isRequestsMatch = false;
}
```

PFB screenshot from Immediate window

[image]

[image]

Comment: breaking the loop right after `isRequestsMatch = false;` will eliminate redundant checks

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I tried solutions mentioned in that link. But i am not able to get desired output. I am trying more regarding the same.

Comment: @max - Good suggestion thanks. I will make that change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if order *matters*, i.e.

```
 {["A", "B"]} != {["B, A"]}   // A and B swapped within the array
```

and

```
 {                   { 
  ["A", "B"],         ["C"],     // [A, B] and [C] arrays are swapped
  ["C"]        !=     ["A, "B"]
 }                   }
```

Then you can check equality with a help of *Linq*:

```
bool equals = (ExpRequestItemsWithSection.Count == ActRequestItemsWithSection.Count) &&
  ExpRequestItemsWithSection
    .Zip(ActRequestItemsWithSection, (left, right) => left.SequenceEqual(right))
    .All(item => item);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer`, but for some obscure reason it is written in an ugly nongeneric way that makes it hard to use as a generic `IEqualityComparer<>`.

If you wrap it like this:

```
class GenericStructuralEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T>
  where T : System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
{
  public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    => System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);

  public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    => System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
}
```

then you can do `SequenceEqauls` on the outer (`List<>`) level:

```
if (!
  ExpRequestItemsWithSection.SequenceEqual(ActRequestItemsWithSection,
    new GenericStructuralEqualityComparer<string[]>())
  )
```

Maybe prettier than the `.Zip` solution?

---

Addition: If you like `.Zip`, you can use `StructuralEqualityComparer` without a wrapping class:

```
if (
  ExpRequestItemsWithSection.Count != ActRequestItemsWithSection.Count
  ||
  ExpRequestItemsWithSection.Zip(ActRequestItemsWithSection,
    System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals)
  .Contains(false)
  )
```

This uses the method group `System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals` whose signature and return type is good enough for a `Func<string[], string[], bool>` which `.Zip` takes (tried with C# 7.3 compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602579/how-to-compare-two-liststring-to-each-other)

```cs
if (a1.SequenceEqual(a2))
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work. I have added screenshot with your suggestion. It is returning false

Comment: var list1 = new List<string>(){"a", "b", "c"};
  var list2 = new List<string>(){"a", "b", "c"};
  
  Console.WriteLine(list1.SequenceEqual(list2).ToString());